# ${file.separator} Resource Filtering In Windows/Unix (Maven Build)

Tags: windows, maven, unix, filepath

I am trying to use `${file.separator}` in my Maven pom files so that the paths can be made universal. I ran the POM file and with filtering my path is getting built fine on Windows.

Filter on XML:

```
<persistenceDirectory>${user.home}${file.separator}app${file.separator}AccessController${file.separator}Persistence</persistenceDirectory>
```

So the final XML gets created as:

```
<persistenceDirectory>C:\Users\\MyLaptop\\app\\AccessController\\Persistence</persistenceDirectory>
```

This is fine when I am coding and testing on Windows, but then I realized, I would have to deploy the webapp on Unix. But I will be building the WAR/JAR on Windows. So I just wanted to know if this will cause a problem? If it wouldn't, you can ignore the rest of my query.

Is there anyway to mock a Unix environment in Windows and Maven. So that that the separator uses `/` instead of `\` when I want to build it for Unix?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Simply use slashes in the pom files or XML files that will work on Windows as well.

Comment: @khmarbaise You mean forward ones?